# Delete a line of text based on conditions from the line above it using python

Tags: python

I am creating a program to edit a text file using the fileinput library. What I want to do is evaluate every line in the text file and if the line above it contains a certain string I want to delete the line below.

for example, If i wanted to remove the line below every line that contained the word "grapes".

The original text would be:

```
I enjoy eating grapes.
Sometimes I apples are good too. 
But I do not line bananas.
```

The result I want to be:

```
I enjoy eating grapes. 
But I do not line bananas.
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = """I enjoy eating grapes.
Sometimes I apples are good too. 
But I do not line bananas."""

result = ""

for line in s.split('\n'):
    if not "apples" in line:
        result += line + '\n'

print(result)
```

Alternatively:

```
result = "\n".join([line for line in s.split('\n') if not "apples" in line])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to create sub-iterators based on a condition. In this case, write a function that takes a line and returns `True` if the line should be removed. Then use groupby to only write lines in "not True" groups.

```
import itertools
import os

filename = "infile.txt"

def line_selector(line):
    return line.startswith("Sometimes I apples are good too.")

with open(filename) as infile, open(filename + ."tmp", "w") as outfile:
    for remove_this, values in itertools.groupby(infile, line_selector):
        if not remove_this:
            outfile.writelines(values)
os.remove(filename)
os.rename(filename + ".tmp", filename)
```